# How to find the lines that where added after being removed in a file with git?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

Consider a file in a git repository, the initial commit of the file contains the following lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Then, let say that in a second commit, `line2` is removed, resulting in the following version of the same file:

```
line1
line3
```

Later, `line2` is added again to the file, whether in the same or different position:

```
line1
line3
line2
```

What is the best way to find the lines that were added after being removed? - `line2` for the above example

#### What I've tried to far?

I've trying parsing the result of `git log -p filename` with `grep` and searching for the diff between added and removed lines. However, this approach doesn't work because the time of addition/deletion of a line in the file is relevant for this problem. I wonder if there is a less dirty way to do this.

Comment: What about `git diff`?

Comment: `git diff HEAD [filename] `

Comment: `git diff [filename] ` compare with index.

Comment: Consider using `git log -S` (search for a diff that changes the number of occurrences of something), `git log -G` (search for a diff that contains a given string-or-pattern), and `git blame`. The blame/annotate method is the most straightforward but for one problem: it can't show you anything about a line that isn't in whatever version you start with, so you often need a `git log -S` to find where it re-appears in history, and let `git blame` work from there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [git diff](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) manual page, 
to see the difference for a file "line.txt" between current and two versions back, here are the commands:

```
$ git diff HEAD^^ HEAD line.txt
$ git diff HEAD^^..HEAD -- line.txt
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD -- line.txt
```

Comment: Your answer works for a limited number of commit back. My question is about getting ALL the lines that were removed once,  and then added again to a file, considering ALL the commit history of the file.